# How to update a global variable inside RDD map operation

Tags: scala, apache-spark, global-variables, rdd

I have RDD[(Int, Array[Double])] and after that, I called a classFunction

```
val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
        (1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)),
        (5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)),
        (1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)),
        (2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)),
        (1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)),
        (5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)),
        (2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2))
      )
    )
 val new_class = new ABC
 new_class.demo(data)
```

Inside class, declared a global variable value =0. Inside the demo() the new variable  new_value = 0 is declared. After the map operation, the new_value get updated and it prints the updated value inside the map.

```
class ABC extends Serializable {
        var value  = 0
        def demo(data_new : RDD[(Int ,Array[Double])]): Unit ={
            var new_value = 0
            data_new.coalesce(1).map(x => {
                if(x._1 == 1)
                    new_value = new_value + 1
                println(new_value)
                value = new_value
            }).count()
            println("Outside-->" +value)
        }
    }
```

OUTPUT:-

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
Outside-->0
```

How can I update the global variable value after the map operation?.

Comment: Are you trying to count the number of occurrences of each key? If so, then there are better ways to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually wanted to know how to update the global variable. This only an example.

Comment: I have tried changing the class ABC() to object ABC(). I got the updated value. 

So why it's not possible to get in class. What's the difference between class and object in global variable declaration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't change the global variables from inside the map.

If you are trying to count the number of one in the function than you can use filter

```
val value = data_new.filter(x => (x._1 == 1)).count 
println("Outside-->" +value)
```

Output:

```
Outside-->3
```

Also it is not recommended to use mutable variables `var`. You should always try to use immutable as `val`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I actually wanted to know how to update the global variable. This only an example.

Comment: rather than example you can add a real implementation

Comment: I have tried changing the class ABC() to object ABC(). I got the updated value. 

So why it's not possible to get in class. What's the difference between class and object in global variable declaration

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about what is it you are doing but you need to use [Accumulators](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators) to perform the type of operations where you need to add values like this.

Here is an example :

```
scala> val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
     |         (1, Array(2.0,5.0,6.3)),
     |         (5, Array(1.0,3.3,9.5)),
     |         (1, Array(5.0,4.2,3.1)),
     |         (2, Array(9.6,6.3,2.3)),
     |         (1, Array(8.5,2.5,1.2)),
     |         (5, Array(6.0,2.4,7.8)),
     |         (2, Array(7.8,9.1,4.2))
     |       )
     | )
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Array[Double])] = ParallelCollectionRDD[83] at parallelize at <console>:24

scala> val accum = sc.longAccumulator("My Accumulator")
accum: org.apache.spark.util.LongAccumulator = LongAccumulator(id: 46181, name: Some(My Accumulator), value: 0)

scala> rdd.foreach { x => if(x._1 == 1) accum.add(1) }

scala> accum.value
res38: Long = 3
```

And as mentioned by @philantrovert, if you wish to count the number of occurrences of each key, you can do the following :

```
scala> rdd.mapValues(_ => 1L).reduceByKey(_ + _).take(3)
res41: Array[(Int, Long)] = Array((1,3), (2,2), (5,2))
```

You can also use `countByKey` but it is to be avoided with big datasets.

Comment: @T.Gawęda Indeed. By I don't know what the OP wants :D I actually never use accumulators.

Comment: But we can't say the you shouldn't use them. But your remark is clearly valid :

Comment: Ok maybe not shouldn't, but shuld with awareness of possible task re-launch

Comment: Ok, modified version, previous comment can't be edited: You should use accumulators inside transformations only when you are aware of task re-launching: `For accumulator updates performed inside actions only, Spark guarantees that each task’s update to the accumulator will only be applied once, i.e. restarted tasks will not update the value. In transformations, users should be aware of that each task’s update may be applied more than once if tasks or job stages are re-executed.`

Answer (score 0):

```
OR You can do achieve your problem in this way also:
class ABC extends Serializable {
        def demo(data_new : RDD[(Int ,Array[Double])]): Unit ={
            var new_value = 0
            data_new.coalesce(1).map(x => {
                if(x._1 == 1)
                  var key = x._1
             (key, 1)
            }).reduceByKey(_ + _)

        }
     println("Outside-->" +demo(data_new))
    }
```